# convert first letters of string in a column of a dataframe to lower cases

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I'm trying to convert first letter of string in a column to lower cases. 
I tried:

```
diamonds %>% map(cut,~substr(.x,1,1)<-tolower(substr(.x,1,1)))
diamonds %>% mutate(cut= map(cut,~substr(.x,1,1)<-tolower(substr(.x,1,1))))
```

Both gave me error messages. I could not figure out why...
BTW, is there any function in stringr that can capitalize the first letter of a string? like str_capitalize?
Appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Drop down to C++ and it's super simple+fast:

```
lc_first <- inline::rcpp(signature(x="std::vector < std::string >"), '
  std::vector < std::string > s = as< std::vector < std::string > >(x);
  unsigned int input_size = s.size();
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<input_size; i++) s[i][0] = tolower(s[i][0]);
  return(wrap(s));
', includes = c("#include <string>", "#include <cctype>"))

lc_first(c("Apple", "Banana", "", "Strawberry"))
## [1] "apple"      "banana"     ""           "strawberry"
```

You need to deal with the factor first in `diamonds`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

lc_first <- inline::rcpp(signature(x="std::vector < std::string >"), '
  std::vector < std::string > s = as< std::vector < std::string > >(x);
  unsigned int input_size = s.size();
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<input_size; i++) s[i][0] = tolower(s[i][0]);
  return(wrap(s));
', includes = c("#include <string>", "#include <cctype>"))

mutate(diamonds, cut = lc_first(as.character(cut)))
## # A tibble: 53,940 x 10
##    carat       cut color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
##    <dbl>     <chr> <ord>   <ord> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
##  1  0.23     ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
##  2  0.21   premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
##  3  0.23      good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
##  4  0.29   premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334  4.20  4.23  2.63
##  5  0.31      good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
##  6  0.24 very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
##  7  0.24 very Good     I    VVS1  62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
##  8  0.26 very Good     H     SI1  61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
##  9  0.22      fair     E     VS2  65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
## 10  0.23 very Good     H     VS1  59.4    61   338  4.00  4.05  2.39
## # ... with 53,930 more rows
```

BUT

I'd only do that if you have *alot* of strings:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rcpp = mutate(diamonds, cut = lc_first(as.character(cut))),
  bsub = mutate(diamonds, cut = sub('^(.)', '\\L\\1', cut, perl=TRUE)),
  times = 1000
) -> mb

mb
## Unit: milliseconds
##  expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
##  rcpp  5.148179  5.69955  6.597025  6.021698  6.563165 88.57958  1000
##  bsub 13.776041 15.25682 16.311123 15.720502 16.701296 88.14688  1000
```

IMO 10ms isn't worth an Rcpp dependency if you aren't processing scads of strings.

I suspect the uppercase version wld not be hard to discern.

On a lark I tried:

```
diamonds$cut <- as.character(diamonds$cut)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rcpp = mutate(diamonds, cut = lc_first(cut)),
  bsub = mutate(diamonds, cut = sub('^(.)', '\\L\\1', cut, perl=TRUE)),
  subs = { 
    substr(diamonds$cut, 1, 1) <- tolower(substr(diamonds$cut, 1, 1))
    diamonds
  },
  times=200
) -> mb

mb
## Unit: milliseconds
##  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
##  rcpp  4.746636  5.157223  5.625221  5.439006  5.801081 10.10990   200
##  bsub 13.154218 13.764529 14.721534 14.251513 15.043204 22.48961   200
##  subs 16.552250 17.377025 19.665733 18.146310 20.256965 90.61097   200
```

(which requires normalizing the factor to a character vector ahead of time)

I surmised `subset() <-` would have been faster, but it's clearly not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\\L` to convert a captured group to lower case in regex, so you can use `sub` to capture the first letter, and replace it with `\\L\\1`, where `\\1` stands for the captured letter, and `\\L` converts it to lower case:

```
head(diamonds)
# A tibble: 6 x 10
#  carat       cut color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#  <dbl>     <ord> <ord>   <ord> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#2  0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#3  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#4  0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334  4.20  4.23  2.63
#5  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#6  0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48

diamonds %>% mutate(cut = sub('^(.)', '\\L\\1', cut, perl=T)) %>% head
# A tibble: 6 x 10
#  carat       cut color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#  <dbl>     <chr> <ord>   <ord> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  0.23     ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#2  0.21   premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#3  0.23      good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#4  0.29   premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334  4.20  4.23  2.63
#5  0.31      good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#6  0.24 very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
```

---

For the second question, may be you need `str_to_title`?

```
stringr::str_to_title("hello world")
# [1] "Hello World"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. BTW, what  was wrong with my approach using mutate and map?

Comment: With `mutate` and `substr`, you can do ``diamonds %>% mutate(cut = `substr<-`(as.character(cut), 1, 1, tolower(substr(cut,1,1))))``. `substr` is vectorized, you don't need `map` here.

Comment: The `map` works in this way ``diamonds %>% mutate(cut= map_chr(cut, ~ `substr<-`(as.character(.x),1,1,tolower(substr(.x,1,1)))))``, i.e. you can't modify object in place within a function.

Comment: Or if you want to use `substr(.x,1,1) <- ` pattern, you need to always return the modified object. `diamonds %>% mutate(cut= map_chr(cut, ~ { .x <- as.character(.x); substr(.x,1,1) <- tolower(substr(.x,1,1)); .x}))`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capitalize the first letter of a string, `str_to_title()` is what you're looking for.

For your other problem, converting to lowercase, you could use regular expressions and `sub`.

```
 > text = 'LonG5 story ShoRt'
 > sub("(\\w)(\\w*)", "\\L\\1\\E\\2", text, perl=TRUE)
 [1] "lonG5 story ShoRt"
```

This regular expression will find any word character and convert the first ocurrence (which would be the first character, I presume) to lowercase, leaving the rest of the matches unchanged.

Applied to your example:

```
untitle = function(text) {
   sub("(\\w)(\\w*)", "\\L\\1\\E\\2", text, perl=TRUE)
}

diamonds %>% mutate(cut = untitle(cut))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the whole data is made of strings then this code below should work:

```
   d=as.data.frame(diamonds[,2:4])
   data=sapply(d,as.character)
   sapply(data,function(x)`substring<-`(x,1,1,tolower(x)))
```

I don't know whether you wanted to change all the columns, or a specific column. I don't know whether your object has a combination of different classes. Hope this will help.

Did you need to change the column names or the elements in the column?